# Recyclerview with twitter fabric

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, twitter-fabric

I'm trying to implement RecyclerView with twitter fabric layout, I'm able to fetch in twitter timeline in Activity onCreate function but it is not being displayed.

```
public class TweetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView listTweetView;
    private TweetTimelineListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TweetAdapter mTweetAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweets);

        listTweetView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_tweet_view);
        listTweetView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication()));

        mTweetAdapter = new TweetAdapter(getApplication());
        listTweetView.setAdapter(mTweetAdapter);


        final TwitterApiClient twitterApiClient = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient();
        final StatusesService statusesService = twitterApiClient.getStatusesService();
        final TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
        statusesService.userTimeline(session.getId(), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                new Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<List<Tweet>> listResult) {
//                        Log.i(TWITTER_USER_TIMELINE_REQUEST, "Successfully retrieved tweets");
//                        TODO Handle empty list
                        Log.d("TweetActivity", "Total tweet count" + listResult.data.size());
                        if (listResult.data != null ){
                            mTweetAdapter.setTweets(listResult.data);
                        }else{

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    }
                });
    }

    public void setListAdapter(TweetTimelineListAdapter listAdapter) {
        this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
    }
}
```

My Adapter looks like this

```
public class TweetAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TweetAdapter.ViewHolderTweet> {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<Tweet> mListTweet ;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;


    public TweetAdapter(Context context){

        layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public TweetAdapter() {}

    @Override
    public ViewHolderTweet onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View  view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_tweets, parent, false);
        ViewHolderTweet viewHolderTweet = new ViewHolderTweet(view);
        return viewHolderTweet;
    }

    public void setTweets(List<Tweet> mListTweet) {
        this.mListTweet = mListTweet;
        //update the adapter to reflect the new set of movies
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderTweet holder, int position) {
        Tweet currentTweet = mListTweet.get(position);

        //Set user details
        User user = currentTweet.user;
        holder.mUserName.setText(user.name);
        holder.mUserHandle.setText(user.screenName);
        loadImages(user.profileImageUrl, holder);

        //retrieved date may be null
//        String createdAt = currentTweet.createdAt;

        holder.mRetweetCount.setText(currentTweet.retweetCount);
        holder.mFavCount.setText(currentTweet.favoriteCount);
        holder.mTweet.setText(currentTweet.text);

//        mPreviousPosition = position;


    }

    private void loadImages(String urlThumbnail, final ViewHolderTweet holder) {
        if (!urlThumbnail.equals(Constants.NA)) {
            mImageLoader.get(urlThumbnail, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    holder.mProfilePic.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mListTweet.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolderTweet extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView mProfilePic;
        private TextView mTweet;
        private TextView mRetweetCount;
        private TextView mFavCount;
        private TextView mUserName;
        private TextView mUserHandle;


        public ViewHolderTweet(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mProfilePic = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_user_image);
            mTweet = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_tweet);
            mRetweetCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_retweet_count);
            mFavCount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fav_count);
            mUserName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name);
            mUserHandle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_handle);


        }
    }

}
```

The layout activity_tweet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activity.TweetsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_tweet_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <!--<include layout="@layout/content_tweets" />-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Any direction would appreciated.

Comment: Where are you caling `setListAdapter()` from?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the setLayoutManager after setting the adapter?

```
            // Set layout manager to position the items
            listTweetView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplication());
```